# How can we close the opened Url through program?

Tags: qt, qt4

I am using `QDesktopServices::openUrl(url);` to open a url.

How can I close that through user defined code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are opening your URL in a browser window, on which user code doesn't have any control.
So basically you cannot close the browser.

A workaround could be that you write a script and detect if a browser is opened on the system, if yes you can close the browser by terminating that process. But I do not recommend this method as it has many security and standard compliance issues on some platforms.

EDIT:

You do not need to create your own browser, just use Qt Webkit to render the opened URL within your own window.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I don't believe you can close a URL via Qt code, with QDesktopServices.

The user could have configured their operating system to open URLs with any number of different browsers, and I don't see how it would be practical for Qt to be coded to know how to close every different type of browser porgramatically, on every different platform they support.

**Edit**

An alternative is to put a browser widget into your application. Then you'll have control over that. Qt provides some pretty powerful tools for is. See the [Qt WebKit](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qtwebkit.html) documentation.

Comment: OK, I've edited my answer to add a note about using Qt WebKit to help you with that.